# For free vs. free of charges

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

They are seems to be similar in meaning, however in a specific context Googling vote for the first.

> ... teaching users **for free**.

I think **free of charge(s)** is more appropriate choice but I couldn't find convincing support for the idea.

Are those really equivalent and what is the best for the context? Is there another alternative?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the mentioned post is close to part of what I've asked, but not exactly same!

Comment: @Eilia, what is it about your post that makes it different?  The answers on the other question seem to cover your concerns (the meaning is the same, but "for free" is generally considered to be more informal).

Answer (score 0):

"free of charge" or "for free" would be correct.
I would say "teaching users for free".
Depending on the context, it might be appropriate to say: 
"a volunteer program teaching users..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any difference in meaning, although "free of charges" is much less common than "free of charge".

Regarding your second question about context: given that English normally likes to adopt the shortest phrasing possible, the longer form "free of charge" can be used as a means of drawing attention to the lack of demand for payment and thus giving it greater emphasis. The same emphasis can be given with the expression "free of *all* charges" (but note that in this expression we normally use the plural **charges** - I'm not sure why!).